# c# database connection.Open() error

Tags: c#, database

Error message keeps coming out pointing on the connection.open() on top ,and i'm unable to solve it after different tries of method imputing , Anyone? thanks!

private void btnRegInfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
     {

        OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection();

        connect.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=:\Users\Student\Desktop\Database11.accdb";
        connect.Open();
    string Name = tbName.Text;

    OleDbCommand cmmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO table1(First Name)Values(@Name)", connect);
    if (connect.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        cmmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", OleDbType.VarWChar, 20).Value = Name;
        try
        {
            cmmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("DATA ADDED");
            connect.Close();
        }
        catch (OleDbException expe)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(expe.Message);
            connect.Close();
        }

    }


    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("CON FAILED");
    }




        if (tbName.Text != "Name" && tbPass.Text != "Password")
            {
                if (tbEmail.Text != "Email" && tbMobile.Text != "Number")
                {
                    if (tbFirstName.Text != "" && tbLastName.Text != "")
                    {
                        const int MIN_LENGTH = 8;

                        string password = tbPass.Text;

                        if (password.Length >= MIN_LENGTH && upperCase(password) >= 1)
                        {
                            r2.Text = "";
                            r2.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            r2.Text = "*Password Is Bad*";
                            r2.ForeColor = Color.Red;
```

Comment: Reading the error message would be a good first step.

Comment: Don't you think telling us what the error message is would be a good first step in solving your issue?

Comment: You need to include the exception message.

Comment: It says the top "connect.Open(); isn't a valid file name, OleDbException occured

Comment: @TeekaaySevenKnights the error is quite obvious right? check your filename then.

Answer (score 2):

Your data source is showing the following: ==>
**Data Source=:\Users\Student\Desktop\Database11.accdb**

I am wondering if you are missing the Drive Letter such as: ==>
**Data Source=c:\Users\Student\Desktop\Database11.accdb**

Comment: Error was InvalidOperationException was handled